# Actual size, fit screen, fill screen icon ideas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, interface-design

Not finding Windows Photo Viewer sufficient enough, I'm coding my own image viewer.

I'll be adding buttons which will perform the following functions:

- actual size (no zoom)
- fit screen (fit the greater side (w or h) inside screen)
- fill screen (fit the lesser side (w or h) inside screen)
- <strike>full screen</strike>

I need icon designs for these buttons. Full Screen icons are common and usually similar to this:

a screenshot from my app

[image]

What I'm wondering is what kind of design can be used to represent other zoom modes: actual size, fit screen, and fill screen?

Photoshop has these buttons, but they have texts inside of them. I rather use icons.

[image]

Do you know any software that uses icons for these modes? If there are not any common/formal icon designs for these, what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Acrobat has a good solution I like with icons that are easy to understand, and when you hover over them, there is a text that clearly states what it does. This allows the text to be longer than on a button.

[image: Acrobat buttons]

Small tip: I noticed that the stroke width in your example is quite thin. Such low contrast can make it hard for some to see what it is, or distinguish from related icons.

Comment: I've added the appropriate Tool Tips to the buttons in case icons seem ambiguous. Since I build this application for personal use, initially at least, icon sizes are not so important. But I might consider making them larger when I make the app public.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to make my own, and I'll use them until I can find something better.

[image]

Also, if anyone is interested in the icons, I can share them.